# Automapper and System.ValueTuple dependency/versioning problem

Tags: asp.net, .net, automapper

I have just added [Automapper](https://automapper.org/) to my asp.net application (.net Framework 4.7), to see hopefully being able to replace some of the tedious manual mapping I always need to do.

I am now having a lot of problems with System.ValueTuple versions. I Notice I have a nuget package for `System.ValueTuple v4.5.0`. If I look into my solutions `packages\System.ValueTuple.4.5.0\lib\net47\System.ValueTuple.dll` I see this as version 4.6.26515.06. If I look into one of the projects I have this nuget package (the one that I added Automapper to), However, when I look in my `bin` folder after a build I have version `4.6.25514.4`, ie and older version to what the nuget package has

When I build the app on the build machine picks up `4.6011.3`. Yet another version!!!

I cannot uninstall the nuget package as it says that Automapper has a dependency on it.

When a user ran the application, they go the yellow screen of death, with

```
  Could not load file or assembly 'System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Does anyone know how to sort out this System.ValueTuple, and know why I seem to be getting random versions of it all over the place?

Thanks in advance!

**[EDIT1]**

Following @Lucian suggestion, I ran the Fusion tool on both my dev machine, and the other machine where it does not work.

I noticed, on my machine the ValueTuple DLL being found in my bin claimed to be version `4.0.2.0`, and not what the file version was.

So I added...

```
 <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.ValueTuple" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.2.0" />
   </dependentAssembly>
```

Previously, on my dev machine if I added any of these `bindingRedirect` I would also get the error, but now, with the above it worked.

However, it did not on the other production (internal test) machine. From that machine I have the following output (once I finally got Fusion to work) ...

```
   *** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (20/11/2018 @ 9:16:49 AM) ***

    The operation failed.
    Bind result: hr = 0x80131040. No description available.

    Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
    Running under executable  c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
    --- A detailed error log follows. 

    === Pre-bind state information ===
    LOG: DisplayName = System.ValueTuple
    (Partial)
    WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
    WRN: Assembly Name: System.ValueTuple | Domain ID: 6
    WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
    WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
    WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
    WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
    WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
    LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/MyApp/
    LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp\bin
    LOG: Dynamic Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\MyApp\0718df87
    LOG: Cache Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\MyApp\0718df87
    LOG: AppName = ab2266c7
    Calling assembly : (Unknown).
    ===
    LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
    LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp\web.config
    LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
    LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
    LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
    LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/MyApp/0718df87/ab2266c7/System.ValueTuple.DLL.
    LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/MyApp/0718df87/ab2266c7/System.ValueTuple/System.ValueTuple.DLL.
    LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/MyApp/bin/System.ValueTuple.DLL.
    LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp\bin\System.ValueTuple.dll
    LOG: Entering download cache setup phase.
    LOG: Assembly Name is: System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
    LOG: A partially-specified assembly bind succeeded from the application directory. Need to re-apply policy.
    LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp\web.config
    LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
    LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
    LOG: Redirect found in application configuration file: 4.0.3.0 redirected to 4.0.2.0.
    LOG: Post-policy reference: System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
    LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
    LOG: The post-policy assembly reference requires probing again.
    LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/MyApp/0718df87/ab2266c7/System.ValueTuple.DLL.
    LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/MyApp/0718df87/ab2266c7/System.ValueTuple/System.ValueTuple.DLL.
    LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/MyApp/bin/System.ValueTuple.DLL.
    LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp\bin\System.ValueTuple.dll
    LOG: Entering download cache setup phase.
    LOG: Assembly Name is: System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
    WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Build Number
    ERR: The assembly reference did not match the assembly definition found.
    ERR: Setup failed with hr = 0x80131040.
    ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.

    *** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (20/11/2018 @ 9:16:49 AM) ***

    The operation failed.
    Bind result: hr = 0x80131040. No description available.

    Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
    Running under executable  c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
    --- A detailed error log follows. 

    === Pre-bind state information ===
    LOG: DisplayName = System.ValueTuple
    (Partial)
    WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
    WRN: Assembly Name: System.ValueTuple | Domain ID: 6
    WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
    WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
    WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
    WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
    WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
    LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/MyApp/
    LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp\bin
    LOG: Dynamic Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\MyApp\0718df87
    LOG: Cache Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\MyApp\0718df87
    LOG: AppName = ab2266c7
    Calling assembly : (Unknown).
    ===
    LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
    LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp\web.config
    LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
    LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
    LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
    LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/MyApp/0718df87/ab2266c7/System.ValueTuple.DLL.
    LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/MyApp/0718df87/ab2266c7/System.ValueTuple/System.ValueTuple.DLL.
    LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/MyApp/bin/System.ValueTuple.DLL.
    LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp\bin\System.ValueTuple.dll
    LOG: Entering download cache setup phase.
    LOG: Assembly Name is: System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
    LOG: A partially-specified assembly bind succeeded from the application directory. Need to re-apply policy.
    LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp\web.config
    LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
    LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
    LOG: Redirect found in application configuration file: 4.0.3.0 redirected to 4.0.2.0.
    LOG: Post-policy reference: System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
    LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
    LOG: The post-policy assembly reference requires probing again.
    LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/MyApp/0718df87/ab2266c7/System.ValueTuple.DLL.
    LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/MyApp/0718df87/ab2266c7/System.ValueTuple/System.ValueTuple.DLL.
    LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/MyApp/bin/System.ValueTuple.DLL.
    LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp\bin\System.ValueTuple.dll
    LOG: Entering download cache setup phase.
    LOG: Assembly Name is: System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
    WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Build Number
    ERR: The assembly reference did not match the assembly definition found.
    ERR: Setup failed with hr = 0x80131040.
    ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

I can see the line `Redirect found in application configuration file: 4.0.3.0 redirected to 4.0.2.0.` which it gets from the `web.config`, and `4.0.2.0` is what should be in the bin folder. This is also the version that shows up in Dotpeek..

[image]

For some reason, it then seems to try and get this DLL from `C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/MyApp`, and it seems to end up with `Assembly Name is: System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51` and then it fails reports..

```
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Build Number
ERR: The assembly reference did not match the assembly definition found.
```

If I remove this `bindingRedirect`, it then reports looking for version `0.0.0.0`. I have no idea what is going on here. The version we are trying to remap to, i.e. `4.0.2.0`, is in the bin folder!

I also deleted the folder `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\MyApp`, but this made no difference.

Any other ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: <dependentAssembly>
 <assemblyIdentity name="System.ValueTuple" publicKeyToken="CC7B13FFCD2DDD51" culture="neutral"/>
 <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.5.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>

Comment: @ Lucian Unfortunately the above makes it yellow screen even on my dev machine (where it normally) works. I have tried just about every combination of the bindingRedirect, tried copying different assembly version on the other troubled machine. I even uninstalled Automapper, and now I always get problems with System.ValueTuple. I wonder what this is for anyway?

Comment: OK, maybe I've got the binding redirect wrong. But as long as you get the versions correct, only one version will be used at runtime and the problem is solved. I'm sure a lot of people already solved this.

Comment: I have uninstalled both ValueTuple and Automapper numerous times. When I add Automapper back it always installs `4.5.0`. This is the only version referenced anywhere. If I follow the reference to the nuget folder, I see file version 4.6.25514.4. On my dev  machine if I add  `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.6.25514.4" />` I get an error `Could not load file or assembly `System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.3.0`. If I remove this, it works on my machine, but not on others (even when I manually copy over the exact DLL into the deployed bin folder. Makes no sense to me at all.

Comment: Fusion log viewer is used to investigate these issues.

Comment: Thanks again @Lucian, I have added some more info after running Fusion log viewer in the main question (see [EDIT1]

Comment: It seems somebody is trying to load the assembly using a partial name, without the version. Find out where and remove that. And no, it's not AM :)

Comment: "somebody"? I only have one project that references this DLL, i.e. the one I added Automapper to.

Comment: After trial and error, the following fixed the problem in my case..`<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />`. So I had to map a version 0.0.0.0 up to 4.0.3.0. Not very comfortable with this, as it makes no sense at all. 1. where does 0.0.0.0  come from. 2. The version in my bin folder is actually `4.0.2.0`, NOT '4.0.3.0`

Comment: Update. NOW the following works `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.2.0" />`. Which is very similar to what @LucianBargaoanu in the first comment, except our dist version is `4.0.2.0`, so I map every version in the universe to this (well up to 5)

Comment: Bottom line is that Microsoft has caused a dependency hell with their bungling of moving from .NET Framework, to .NET Standard to .NET Core...and all the intermediate packages and support. IT's a freaking nightmare, and no one at Microsoft seems to have a real answer other than "get the latest Visual Studio and start using .NET Core" Yeah, because we have inexhaustible budgets to constantly buy the latest and greatest IDE, and fix all the incompatibilities in our code.